# I copy my code from .ttf file to putty there is messy code

Tags: osx, putty, ttf

My mac editor:

[image]

My code in the .ttf file:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And copy to my putty, there is messy code here:

[image]

Comment: Guessing putty does not support (or is not set-up for) UTF-8 and the other terminal is. Might be an option in putty to enable UTF-8 support.

Comment: We would need to see a textual hex dump, or have more details on what encodings are used in what. Perhaps the quotes are “smart” and thus become mojibake when a different encoding is assumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your current character settings in PuTTY with `echo $LANG`

If it is not an UTF-8 derivative (such as `en_US.UTF-8`) then close your session, and create a new saved session with the hostname/IP if you haven't already.

Highlight the session, then expand the `window` config, select `translation` and you will be able to select your character encoding there:
[image: Putty config]

Start your session and you should be able to paste your UTF-8 characters as expected.